# Soundcloud API: ResponseError in all tracks from one artist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soundcloud

I'm trying to access a track from Soundcloud through their API, but I'm having problems accessing the tracks from this particular artist: [link](https://soundcloud.com/lyar).

I'm using ruby on rails and the soundcloud-ruby gem.

For example, I tried to access [this](https://soundcloud.com/lyar/lyar-cool-ft-matthew-j-kurz) track with these methods:

```
curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/267810877?client_id=my_client_id"
```

```
sc_track_url="https://soundcloud.com/lyar/lyar-cool-ft-matthew-j-kurz"
client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => ENV['SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID'])
sc_track = client.get('/resolve', :url => sc_track_url)
```

```
client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => ENV['SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID'])
sc_track = client.get('/tracks/267810877')
```

The curl call doesn't return anything, and the other two calls returns:

```
SoundCloud::ResponseError: SoundCloud::ResponseError
```

I'm able to fetch tracks even when the artist disabled their stream, or the track sharing is set to private, so I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the API, or if I'm using it the wrong way.

Comment: did you put your appropriate client id in curl command. Silly, but sometimes it goes out of mind!

Comment: And as far as ruby gem is concerned, have you set the environment variables that you are accessing through ENV ?. I suggest you go to irb and check if `ENV['SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID']` gives the appropriate result, and then try.

Comment: Well, I can't ask you for client_id, without which its little difficult to know the problem. Nevertheless, can you give me link to the API documentation page where you saw the documentation of that curl command for accessing the track?

Comment: @HarshTrivedi Yes, I checked it multiple times and the client_id is right, because I can access other tracks without a problem. Here is the documentation about that curl command: developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm seeing something similar!

Comment: Unfortunately no @MartinCleaver, it's still happening with multiple artists

Comment: That sucks. I've now stopped using a substantial integration that I'd built.